# Type Inference in Haskell v. Scala

Tags: scala, haskell, type-inference

Given the following code:

```
Prelude> let f x = if (x) then 55 else "foo"
```

Why does the compiler look for a `Num [Char]`?

```
<interactive>:2:23:
    No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from the literal `55'
    In the expression: 55
    In the expression: if (x) then 55 else "foo"
    In an equation for `f': f x = if (x) then 55 else "foo"
```

However, in Scala, it will find the least-upper bound of `55` and `"foo"`, which is `Any`:

```
scala> def f(x: Boolean) = if (x) 55 else "foo"
f: (x: Boolean)Any

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> lub( List[Type]( typeOf[Int], typeOf[String] ) )
res4: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Any
```

What's the key difference between Haskell's and Scala's Type Inference?

Comment: The key difference is that Scala has subtyping and Haskell doesn't. A less fundamental difference is probably that numbers aren't polymorphic in Scala, though I'm not enough of an expert in Scala to say that for sure.

Comment: The compiler looks for `Num [Char]` because `"foo"` is a string, i.e. a `[Char]`, and occurs in the other branch of `55`. This means that `55` must be of type `[Char]` as well, and a way to interpret the number `55` as a string is searched (said instance).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add an instance for `Num [Char]` in Haskell, if that's what you want:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Composition ((.:))  -- cabal install composition

helper :: (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> (String -> String -> String)
helper op = show .: on op read

cast :: (Integer -> Integer) -> (String -> String)
cast f = show . f . read

instance Num [Char] where
    fromInteger = show
    (+) = helper (+)
    (-) = helper (-)
    (*) = helper (*)
    abs = cast abs
    signum = cast signum
    negate = cast negate
```

where this is just one possible implementation.  This will make your example compile:

```hs
> let f x = if x then 55 else "foo"
> f True
"55"
> f False
"foo"
```

Haskell has polymorphic numeric literals, so `55 :: Num a => a`, and since both branches of an `if` must return the same type, you are forcing `a ~ [Char]` by having the `else` branch return `"foo"`.  This leads to a somewhat confusing error message, but it can be a very powerful feature.  It means that any numeric literal can act as the type you need it to be, and it's the same concept behind the `OverloadedStrings` extension, allowing you to have polymorphic string literals instead of using `pack` everywhere you need a `Text` or `ByteString`.

Scala uses subtyping and has a generic type for all values.  It allows you to relax the type safety on a function and return literally `Any`thing.  Haskell does not have subtyping at all, so the only way to unify those types (similar to finding the LUB) is to use the fact that numeric literals are polymorphic under the `Num` constraint, so in order to compile `"foo"` has to implement `Num`.  Actually, if you enabled `OverloadedStrings` `f` will compile just fine with the type

```
f :: (Data.String.IsString a, Num a) => Bool -> a
```

There aren't any types by default that meet both constraints, but GHC will happily accept this as a valid function.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of how number literals are interpreted in Haskell.

```
λ> :type 412
412 :: Num a => a
```

What this is doing behind-the-scenes is calling the `Num` class `fromInteger` function to convert `412`, or in your case, `55`, into whatever instance.

We can look at the `Num` class like this:

```
λ :info Num
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  negate :: a -> a
  abs :: a -> a
  signum :: a -> a
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
```

So, when you write `55` and `"foo"`, Haskell first realises that the return value must be of type `[Char]`, because `"foo" :: [Char]`, and tries to find an instance of `Num` that matches that. It fails, of course.

Scala is a very much less strictly-typed language, and, because it has no type-classes exactly like Haskell's, so can only resort to `Any` to describe types like that. I don't think I have to explain why that's not great, because type errors are never fun.

---

If you want to be able to return either an `Int` or `String`, you can use `Either`:

```
f :: Bool -> Either Int String
f b = if b then Left 55 else Right "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're still somewhat confused, it helps to understand a little of how the back-end works.

In Haskell, a typeclass is **a dictionary of functions associated with a type**. Each type can only have one dictionary of functions for each typeclass. When it does, we say that it *satisfies* the associated *constraint*. So if you type `:t 5` into GHCi it will tell you that the type of 5 is `Num a => a`, in other words, there are many types which have a value of `5` and those types are ones which have a `Num` dictionary. This is true because the `Num` dictionary defines the `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a` function which takes the specific `5` of type `Integer` and casts it to that other type.

So it's complaining that it does not have the `Num` dictionary defined for the `String` type -- and *of course* it doesn't, because people don't usually use strings as numbers. (The type `String` is an alias for `[Char]`.)

So when you write:

```
let f x = if x then 55 else "foo"
```

then here is what happens:

1. Haskell is strongly typed and `if` is an expression with a concrete return value with a concrete type. Both branches must have the same type.
2. GHC knows that and discerns, first off, that the type of `x` is `x :: Bool` (because it appears as the test of an if-branch and Haskell's strong types don't allow non-explicit coercion) and that `55 :: Num x => x` while `"foo" :: String`.
3. GHC now **unifies** those last two types. It does this by merging the constraints separately from merging the types, so it merges `x` with `String` to find out that `x = String` on a type-level.
4. GHC propagates the constraint to the result of that to say that the type is `Num String => String`.
5. GHC complains because it does not know what the `Num` dictionary for `String` looks like.

How do you solve this problem? The easiest way is to use the data structure `data Either x y = Left x | Right y` that comes built-in with Haskell:

```
let f x = if x then Left 55 else Right "foo"
```

The type of the output is then `Num x => Either x String`, which is totally fine and does not unify the two at all. **Caution**: Due to a thing called the "monomorphism restriction", which is set by default in GHC but not GHCi, if you don't provide an explicit type annotation saying otherwise, `f` may reduce the `Num a => Either a String` to `Either Integer String`:

```
Prelude> :set -XMonomorphismRestriction
Prelude> let f x = if x then Left 55 else Right "foo"
Prelude> :t f
f :: Num a => Bool -> Either a [Char]
Prelude> let f = \x -> if x then Left 55 else Right "foo"
Prelude> :t f
f :: Bool -> Either Integer [Char]
```